# O(B) algorithm to find positions of all permutations of smaller string in a bigger string with length B - how is this possible?

Tags: strings, hash, permutations, substrings

Context: I've been working through Cracking the Code Interview and on page 70 the book asserts that there is a O(B) solution to this problem.

If

- s = little string and S = len(s)
- b = big string and B = len(b)

then I believe it would be something along the lines of (pseudocode):

```
hs = hash(s)
for every position, substring of length S in B: 
    h_sub = hash(substring)
    if hs == h_sub:
         print position
```

Note that the `for` loop will run `B-S+1` times, so whatever happens inside the loop must be O(1) in order for the whole thing to be O(B).

This assumes that there exists a O(1) hash function `hash(s)` that only returns the same hash when two words are permutations of each other, and never collide otherwise.

**What is this hash function?** It seems like you'd have to iterate through every letter in `substring` to calculate `h_sub` and I don't see how that can happen in less than O(S) time. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33325485/3700490) seemed promising but then someone found a non-valid collision.

I learned about the [radix-2p hash](http://www.cs.unc.edu/~zsguo/comp550/slides/note_hashing.pdf) for this problem in school and we had to prove it as a homework exercise so I am convinced of its correctness.

However in the calculation $k = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} x_i(2^{p})^i$, the exponent on the $2^p$ always changes depending on the position of the letter $x_i$ within the substring, so I don't see how we can avoid having to iterate anew through all S letters of the substring when we calculate $k \text{ mod } (2^p-1)$.

Am I missing something or is there another approach entirely? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I think a hash is the wrong approach. Instead you can use auxiliary variables: an array $A$ and an integer $c$. Basically $A$ tracks the error in the number of occurrences of each character and $c$ tracks the number of non-zero errors. Instead of a hash update you update the count of the character which drops out, then update $c$ if it changed from or to zero, then repeat for the character which is coming in. After that, if $c=0$ you found a permutation of $s$.

Answer (score 1):

One simple hash is

$$\text{hash}(s) = s[0] + s[1] + \dots + s[n-1] \bmod p,$$

where $s[0],\dots,s[n-1]$ are the characters of the string $s$.  You could also replace addition modulo $p$ with xor, or any other commutative operation.  You also need the hash to be a [rolling hash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolling_hash) so that you can compute $\text{hash}(B[i+1..i+k])$ from $\text{hash}(B[i..i+k-1])$ efficiently, but fortunately the above hash functions have that property.

The worst-case running time could be $O(|s| \cdot |B|)$ (because in principle you could have a hash collision in every position), but in practice it will often run in time $O(|B|)$ if the strings $s,B$ aren't "too unfriendly".

If you want stronger guarantees, or just want to heuristically reduce hash collisions, here is a better hash:

$$\text{hash}(s) = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} T[s[i]] \bmod p,$$

where $T[\cdot]$ is a lookup table with one entry per possible character value.  (For example, if every character is a 8-bit byte, then $T$ is a lookup table with 256 entries.)  This hash will have fewer collisions, and still has all the properties needed -- it is commutative and a rolling hash.   If you fill in the entries of $T$ randomly, one can prove stronger guarantees: the expected running time will be $O(|B|)$, and the running time will be at most $c \cdot |B|$ with probability exponentially small in $c$ (so in practice the running time can be upper-bounded by something like $100 \cdot |B|$ for all intents and purposes).  This is a consequence of the fact that $\Pr[\text{hash}(s) = \text{hash}(t)] \le 1/p$ for all $s \ne t$, when $T$ is initialized in this way.

Comment: Ah I see! Thanks. If I understand correctly, the idea is that I use a rolling hash, but only when there is a collision do I check every letter of `s` against every letter of `substring`. And collisions should be uncommon enough that runtime will average out to O(B) in practice. This satisfies me for all practical purposes :) But does this mean there is no "true" O(B) algorithm in a strict sense?

Comment: @SlugFrisco, yup, exactly!  I've edited my answer to describe a hash function where we can prove a stronger fact about the running time; in some rigorous sense it can reasonably be considered $O(|B|)$.